# Array/object parameter in octopus custom step template

Tags: octopus-deploy

Is there a way to add array/object parameter to octopus custom step template?
Built in step "Deploy to IIS" allows to add collection of bindings. Can such functionality be added to a custom step?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to setup an array parameter for a custom step template. See [Custom Step Templates documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/deployment-process/steps/custom-step-templates).

You could [put an array into a variable and parse that with Powershell](https://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/1557-passing-an-array-as-a-variable-to-predeploy-script). Also, [here is a custom step template example](https://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/54930-pass-array-of-variables-into-underlying-powershell-script).

You could reach out to [Octopus Support](https://help.octopusdeploy.com/) to see if they have any other recommendations or maybe add it to their [UserVoice](https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/) to see if others are interested in the feature.